# How do I this SQL query in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a database like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5dc5fb6bee47789e9024f817"),
    "parentTableID" : "1",
    "time_created" : "2019-11-09 02:29:57.233032636 +0330 +0330",
    "dataType" : "CellFDD",
    "parentTableName" : "ENodeBFunction",
    "properties" : {
        "CellFDD_zzzTemporary71" : "-2000000000",
        "CellFDD_node" : "LB0300ZB1",
        "CellFDD_acBarringFactor" : "95",
        "CellFDD_pdcchTargetBlerPCell" : "22",
        "CellFDD_zzzTemporary32" : "-2000000000",
        "CellFDD_zzzTemporary22" : "-2000000000",
        "CellFDD_cellRange" : "-15"
        }

"_id" : ObjectId("5dc5fb6bee47789e9024f818"),
    "parentTableID" : "1",
    "time_created" : "2019-11-09 02:29:57.233032636 +0330 +0330",
    "dataType" : "CellTDD",
    "parentTableName" : "NodeBFunction",
    "properties" : {
        "CellTDD_zzzTemporary71" : "-2000000000",
        "CellTDD_node" : "LB0301ZB1",
        "CellTDD_acBarringFactor" : "96",
        "CellTDD_pdcchTargetBlerPCell" : "23",
        "CellTDD_zzzTemporary32" : "-2000000000",
        "CellTDD_zzzTemporary22" : "-2000000000",
        "CellTDD_qRxLevMin" : "-128"
        }
```

How to do this SQL query to mongodb, how do I union parametername, realvalue, elementname, policyvalue from documents with different dataType field in mongo

```
SELECT
    'CellFDD' as MO ,
    'cellRange' as parameterName ,
    a.node as elementName ,
    a."cellRange" as realValue ,
    '15' as policyValue 
FROM
    "R_EL"."CellFDD" a

WHERE
    a."cellRange" :: numeric != '15'

UNION

SELECT
    'CellTDD' as MO ,
    'qRxLevMin' as parameterName ,
    a.node  as elementName ,
    a."qRxLevMin" as realValue ,
    '-126<X<-120' as policyValue 
FROM
    "R_EL"."CellTDD" a
WHERE
    a."qRxLevMin" :: numeric > '-120'
    AND
    a."qRxLevMin" :: numeric < '-126'
```

I try this query:

```
db.coll.aggregate([{$match:{$or:[{"dataType":"CellFDD"},{"dataType":"CellTDD"}]}},{$project:{_id:0,MO:{$cond:{if:{$eq:["$dataType","CellFDD"]},then:"CellFDD",else:{$cond:{if:{$eq:["$dataType","CellTDD"]},then:"CellTDD",else:""}}}},Parametername:{$cond:[{$and:[{$eq:["$dataType","CellTDD"]},{$or:[{$lt:["$properties.CellTDD_qRxLevMin","-120"]},{$gt:["$properties.CellTDD_qRxLevMin","-126"]}]}]},"qRxLevMin",{$cond:[{$and:[{$eq:["$dataType","CellFDD"]},{$ne:["$properties.CellFDD_cellRange","15"]}]},"cellRange",""}}}}])
```

Comment: can you provide an example of the output results you wish to achieve based on the example documents you've show please?

Comment: I'd like to export data with 4 column (MO,Parametername,RealValue,PolicyValue) ex:CellFDD,CellRange,-15,15

Comment: There is no UNION or JOIN in Mongo. For that purpose you can use `lookup`

Comment: You may use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) as SQL `UNION`. @Daniyal Lukmanov `$lookup` is not appropiate for this query.